# How to use STL functions in OpenJDK development?

Tags: java, c++

I need to use STL functions in JDK source code and compile and build the program (java).
When I use any STL functions, for eg `std::vector <int> testingVector;`, it gives the following error.

```
Warning: No SCM configuration present and no .src-rev
/home/srcshetty/Desktop/TheProjectParGC/ProjectParGC/ProjectParGC/JDK13_Dev/build/linux-x86_64-server-slowdebug/hotspot/variant-server/libjvm/objs/test.o: Error: Use of global operators new and delete is not allowed in Hotspot:
                 U operator delete(void*)
See: /home/srcshetty/Desktop/TheProjectParGC/ProjectParGC/ProjectParGC/JDK13_Dev/make/hotspot/lib/CompileJvm.gmk
make[3]: *** [lib/CompileJvm.gmk:304: /home/srcshetty/Desktop/TheProjectParGC/ProjectParGC/ProjectParGC/JDK13_Dev/build/linux-x86_64-server-slowdebug/hotspot/variant-server/libjvm/objs/test.o.op_check] Error 1
make[3]: *** Waiting for unfinished jobs....
make[2]: *** [make/Main.gmk:249: hotspot-server-libs] Error 2
```

I thought it could be a problem with compilation for a different standard. So I changed the compilation standard from gnu++98 to c++14 in here
`{JDK13_Dev}/make/autoconf/flags-cflags.m4` (path)

```
$1_CXXSTD_CXXFLAG="**-std=c++14**"
    FLAGS_CXX_COMPILER_CHECK_ARGUMENTS(ARGUMENT: [${$1_CXXSTD_CXXFLAG} -Werror],
        PREFIX: $3, IF_FALSE: [$1_CXXSTD_CXXFLAG=""])
    $1_TOOLCHAIN_CFLAGS_JDK_CXXONLY="${$1_CXXSTD_CXXFLAG}"
    $1_TOOLCHAIN_CFLAGS_JVM="${$1_TOOLCHAIN_CFLAGS_JVM} ${$1_CXXSTD_CXXFLAG}"
    $2ADLC_CXXFLAG="${$1_CXXSTD_CXXFLAG}"
```

But still, it gives the same error as before (And I could not find anywhere else I can change the target standard for compilation).

Could someone please tell me if it's possible to use STL functions inside the OpenJDK source code and build the program successfully?.

Comment: This and other similar: https://bugs.openjdk.java.net/browse/JDK-8010992

Comment: Does it mean that I won't be able to call a new operator anywhere in OpenJDK source code? @RichardCritten